# Share Intent For Multiple Url Images

Tags: android

I would like to share multiple images from URL using a share intent (currently testing by choosing to share with Whatsapp). However only the last image from the URL is being shared and not all the images are shared at once as expected.

my share method code below:

```
    public void shareItem() {

        ArrayList<Uri> arrList_Uri = new ArrayList<Uri>();
        Uri uri;

        int img_position = 0;
        for (String strURI : arrListStr_Images_Checked) {

            uri = Uri.parse(strURI);
            arrList_Uri.add(uri);

            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(arrListStr_Images_Checked.get(img_position)).into(new Target()
            {
                @Override public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                    shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
                    shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, arrList_Uri);          
                    shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, getLocalBitmapUri(bitmap));
                    shareIntent.setType("image/png");
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share with"));
                }
                @Override public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

                }
                @Override public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

                }
            });

            img_position++;
        }
    }
    public Uri getLocalBitmapUri(Bitmap bmp) {
        Uri bmpUri = null;
        try {
            File file =  new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "share_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".png");
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
            out.close();
            bmpUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bmpUri;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be used to send the heterogeneous file list (like image, document and video at same time), for instance uploading downloaded documents, images at same time.

```
public static void shareMultiple(List<File> files, Context context){

    ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<>();
    for(File file: files){
        uris.add(Uri.fromFile(file));
    }
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, context.getString(R.string.ids_msg_share)));
}
```

**NB:**

Starting in `API 24`, sharing file `URIs` will cause a `FileUriExposedException`. To remedy this, you can either switch your `compileSdkVersion` to 23 or lower or you can use content URIs with a [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing.html).

But since Google recently announced that new apps and app updates would be required to target `SDK 28` versions of Android for release to the Play Store. That said, targeting API 23 or lower is no longer a valid option if you plan to release the app to the store. You must go the `FileProvider` route.